# How to getElementsByClassName and apply another getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to set a html `img` within a button `.button__image` and change a hidden span to `display:block;` on an image error (across multiple classes, which is why I'm not using `getElementById`), but I'm receiving an error:

ERROR

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByClassName(...).addEventListener is not a function
```

HTML

```
<img src="images/logo_image.svg" class="button__image"><span class="hidden"/>stuff</span>
```

JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button__image").addEventListener("error", unhideHiddenFunction);

function unhideHiddenFunction() {
    alert('image error');
    document.getElementsByClassame("hidden").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns collection, use index........`document.getElementsByClassName("button__image")[0].addEventListener....`

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work.

Comment: What is the error after fix? You also have typo in `document.getElementsByClassame("hidden").style.display = "block";`

Comment: Good catch on the typo, that fixed some of it. Getting this error now: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined`

Comment: Fixed: `var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
 for (var i=0;i<elems.length;i+=1){
   elems[i].style.display = 'block';
 }`